# Get right element in each that matches a string

Tags: jquery, this, each, element

I wanna loop over DOM elements using `.each()` and find a certain element that has the same `.text()` as a variable. A problem occurs, if the correct element is the last sibling.

Example:

```
<p> wrong </p>
<p> wrong </p>
<p> right </p>
```

It will go through both wrong elements before going to the correct one in this code. I can't remove the `else` because I need to see if none of the elements has this text and if they don't, something else should happen. Now it will be false twice and will create 2 new `<p>` and then when it reaches the last element it will throw the `alert()`. Is there any other way to do this?

```
$('p').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == "right") {
        alert("this exists already");
        return false;
    } else {
        // A p will be created with text right
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't know what's the issue or your question

Comment: I haven't understood your question. Please explain it in a better way.

Comment: Basicly i wanna iterate throught the elements and if there is a element that has the text "right" in it , the loop should stop and alert the user. It should not do the else condition since we have an element with the text() right

@Popnoodles Can you show me and code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is what you're asking for.

```
// We care that it exists or not
var already_exists = false;
// Iterate through the existing elements
$('p').each(function() {
    // If it exists, store that and break the loop because we don't need to check any more
    if ($(this).text() == "right") {
        already_exists = true;
        return false;
    }
});

// If, after checking (possibly) all elements, it exists, shout, else create it
if (already_exists){
   alert("this exists already");
}else{
   // A p will be created with text right
}
```

Note

I'm not sure, without checking, that `.text()` on `<p> right </p>` will match "`right`" because of white-space. You may want to trim it. `if ($.trim($(this).text()) == "right")`

Answer (score 1):

Can use `filter()` for this and you need to remove whitespace or your match won't work based on what is shown in question.

```
var myVar = 'right';

var exists = $('p').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim() === myVar;
}).length;// length of collection will determine if filter has matches

if(!exists){
   // add element
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to loop at all.

Just use the [:contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector.

```js
// alert the user if there is at least one <p>right</p> element
if ($('p:contains("right")').length) {
  alert("this exists already");
  
} else {
  // A p will be created with text right
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> wrong </p>
<p> wrong </p>
<p> right </p>
```

Comment: Note that `:contains` and absolute match are not the same thing

Comment: @charlietfl That's correct. But it all boils down on how the OP wants to implement this. If "right" is controlled by him (without user input), then your solution solves his problem, otherwise my solution would be more appropriate.

Comment: This makes most sense

Comment: Now the text i am checking with is in a variable. so how would this work if i had a variable instead of "right"

Comment: @saman93 Assuming your variable is `value`, then use concatenation: `if ($('p:contains("' + value + '")').length) {`

Comment: Also i belive @charliefl solution would be the one to go for since it has to be an exact match. Because one of the elements could have the same name but being different by having an number example: right and right1 could exist

Comment: @saman93 In that case, charliefl solution is better. But, personally I would control this through the use of classes, not content.

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos ofc , but i will control it with values instead, most likely will redo to classes just to change the css

Answer (score 0):

the problem in text space before and after so please trim your text like the following

```
if ($.trim($(this).text())== "right") {}
```